# How to get arguments passed to remote bash alias/function when executed via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am using

```
ssh -t <remote-host> bash -ic run_it 100
```

where run_it is defined like:

```
run_it() { echo Hello $1 }
```

On the remote machine it runs fine.

Arguments not getting passed when run using ssh.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `run_it` *cannot* be defined like that, because what you show is not a (complete) valid function definition.  Perhaps you meant `run_it() { echo Hello $1; }`, though it would be better to quote the parameter expansion: `run_it() { echo Hello "$1"; }`.  Not that that resolves the issue.

Comment: You don't pass any parameter to your function. The `-c` option of bash accepts a single argument, and this is just `run_it`, without parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another, now deleted, answer pointed out, when you use `bash -c`, the command to run is the next *single* argument, and the one after, if any, is a string to use as `$0`.  Subsequent ones are interpreted as positional parameters *for the shell*, but that does not help you because for your purposes, you need arguments for the command *inside* the shell.

The best approach is probably to quote the command you want run in the shell.  I find, however, that I need to *double* quote it:

```
ssh -t <remote-host> bash -ic "'run_it 100'"
```

One level of quotes will be removed by the local shell in which you execute the command.  The fact that you need (or I do, anyway) the additional quotes seems to indicate that the specified command is being run on the remote side *via a shell*, rather than directly.  I do not find that detail documented, and it's not what I expected, but there you have it.